# Can I get a 2-year Canada student visa for a 1-year program?

Tags: canada, study

I am a Nigerian and gained admission into Cambrian College to study pre- health sciences. The course length is 1 year.

What is the maximum length of time of a visa issued for a study course like this? Can I still be granted a 2-year visa when the course is for 1 year?

Comment: In general, you can apply for and be granted visas that match the period of time when you are a full time student.   Generally, you can not ask for a two year visa for a one year program however if you require more than one year to complete a one year program you can apply for an extension.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Student visas are given for the period of study. You enrol for a year, you get a one-year visa. Once you leave school, your status as a student expires, and thus your visa.

If you want two years, at the end of the first year you'll have to re-enrol...